# Make a 301 redirect with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I want to make redirect 301:

`http://www.example.com/en/index.html` to be `http://www.example.com/en/`.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code work, I have made just a little change. L=301.

Comment: Yes intention is always to use 301 eventually after testing with 302.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version :

```
Redirect 301 /en/ /en/index.html
```